# Convert nested objects containing mixture of arrays and objects into a different structure using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I am having a nested object that looks like this. This contains nested arrays and objects inside it. It looks like this,

```
const input = {
  result: {
    data: {
      groupMapper: [
        {
          id: "id123",
          groupName: "Group 1",
          subGroups: []
        },
        {
          id: "id456",
          groupName: "Group 2",
          subGroups: []
        }
      ],
      items: [
        {
          id: "abc",
          itemName: "Item1",
          groupId: "id123",
          isDefault: true,
          value: 1,
          config: {
            saved: true
          }
        },
        {
          id: "def",
          itemName: "Item2",
          groupId: "id456",
          value: 2,
          isDefault: false,
          config: null
        },
        {
          id: "hgi",
          itemName: "Item3",
          groupId: "id123",
          isDefault: true,
          value: 3,
          config: {
            saved: true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
};
```

I want this grouped with respect to the ids present in `groupMapper` and `items`. So basically entries inside `items` array should be grouped with respect to `groupId` of the ``groupMapper`and should be part of new object in the output result. Also if an entry inside`items`has`saved`flag true should be put as`used: true`after grouping in the final object, If its null, then add it as`false`. The properties should be renamed to the following manner in the output result.

https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-nova-8flr9o?file=/src/index.js:1542-1759

```
const output = {
  id123: {
    categoryId: "id123",
    categoryName: "Group 1",
    tiles: [
      {
        tileId: "abc",
        tileName: "Item1",
        groupId: "id123",
        isDefault: true,
        value: 1,
        used: true
      },
      {
        tileId: "hgi",
        tileName: "Item3",
        groupId: "id123",
        isDefault: true,
        value: 3,
        used: true
      }
    ]
  },
  id456: {
    categoryId: "id456",
    categoryName: "Group 2",
    tiles: [
      {
        tileId: "def",
        tileName: "Item2",
        groupId: "id456",
        isDefault: false,
        value: 2,
        used: false
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Here there are two entries has groupId `id123` and one has `id456`. Hence tiles will have two entries in the first group and second one has just one entry. Also `used` flag is made as true because `config.saved` was true and in the other case its null hence false is put for `used`

Code that I tried

```
const { result } = input;
const res = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(result).map(([key, value], index) => {
    return [key, { ...value, tiles: value.items, used: value.items.config }];
  })
);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: What is the relevance of `subGroups`?

Comment: It is not letting me edit. For now it will be a part of final object at the first level `id456: { categoryId: "id456", categoryName: "Group 2", subGroups:[], tiles: [.......]}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first create the output structure with empty `tiles` arrays, based on the `groupMapper` data.

Then iterate the input items and populate the associated `tiles` arrays:

```js
const input = {result: {data: {groupMapper: [{id: "id123",groupName: "Group 1",subGroups: []},{id: "id456",groupName: "Group 2",subGroups: []}],items: [{id: "abc",itemName: "Item1",groupId: "id123",isDefault: true,value: 1,config: {saved: true}},{id: "def",itemName: "Item2",groupId: "id456",value: 2,isDefault: false,config: null},{id: "hgi",itemName: "Item3",groupId: "id123",isDefault: true,value: 3,config: {saved: true}}]}}};

const {groupMapper, items} = input.result.data;
const output = Object.fromEntries(groupMapper.map(grp => [grp.id, {
    categoryId: grp.id,
    categoryName: grp.groupName,
    subGroups: grp.subGroups,
    tiles: []
}]));

for (const item of items) {
    output[item.groupId].tiles.push({
        tileId: item.id,
        tileName: item.itemName,
        groupId: item.groupId,
        isDefault: item.isDefault,
        value: item.value,
        user: !!item.config?.saved
    })
}

console.log(output);
```